# How might I handle a double click event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

Is there a way to bind an event handler to a double click with jQuery instead of single click?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, jQuery has a [`dblclick()`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event:

```
$("div").dblclick(function() {
  alert("double clicked");
});
```

One warning, from the docs:

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to
>   both the `click` and `dblclick` events
>   for the same element

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use the [`$.dblclick()`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) method:

```
$(".foo").dblclick(function(){
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#name_object").dblclick(function(){
// your code
});
```

I think help you.